# Showing that $\mathbf{F} = \cos(xy)yz^2\mathbf{i} +\cos(xy)xz^2\mathbf{j} + 2\sin(xy)z\mathbf{k}$ is a conservative vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I am supposed to show that $\mathbf{F} = \cos(xy)yz^2\mathbf{i} +\cos(xy)xz^2\mathbf{j} + 2\sin(xy)z\mathbf{k}$ is a conservative vector field.

In order for $\mathbf{F}$ to be a conservative vector field:
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=\left[\begin{array}\\
\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} 
\end{array}\right] = 0
$$
$$\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} = 2xz\cos(xy)-2xz\cos(xy)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} = 2yz\cos(xy)-2yz\cos(xy)=0$$
However:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} &= z^2\left[\cos(xy)-x^2\sin(xy)\right] - z^2\left[\cos(xy)-y^2\sin(xy)\right] \\
&=z^2(y^2-x^2)\sin(xy)
\end{align*}
How is that meant to equal 0?

Comment: $$\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} = z^2 (\cos(xy) - \color{red}{xy} \sin(xy)).$$  Same goes for $\partial F_x / \partial y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just computed the partial derivatives wrong. Indeed

$$\partial_1F_2(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl(\cos(xy)xz^2\bigr)=z^2(\cos(xy)\color{red}{-xy}\sin(xy)),$$

$$\partial_2F_1(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigl(\cos(xy)yz^2\bigr)=z^2(\cos(xy)\color{red}{-xy}\sin(xy)),$$

and so

$$\partial_1F_2(x,y,z)-\partial_2F_1(x,y,z)=0.$$